# Astrologer's view of the planets' position

Tags: archaeoastronomy

Assuming there was a standard for (early) astrological calculations, did the astrologers have a 2- or 3-D view of the planets' position?

Comment: Early astrologers, just like early astronomers and navigators, related positions to the ["celestial sphere"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_sphere). Does that count as 2D or 3D?

Comment: In the Wikipedia article about "Celestial spheres" (plural) the planets are depicted in a 2D arrangement within "thick spheres of rarefied matter nested one within the other".

Comment: Those are from cosmological models later developed by ancient Greeks. Once they were developed, astrologers started referencing them too, e.g. Ptolemy himself wrote [Tetrabiblos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrabiblos). But those were theoretical speculations disconnected from positioning and calculations, Greeks did not have observational means for thickness and composition to matter. In practice, trajectories were all projected to a single sphere.

Comment: - and on a great circle on the sphere as an intersection with a plane?

Comment: Mostly, especially in the early times. Ptolemy was aware of [lunar evection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evection), small wobbling around the orbital plane. [Eudoxian orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentric_spheres) were theoretically non-planar, but that was hardly supported by observations.

Comment: See [Taking Latitude with Ptolemy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41134229) on non-planar motions in epicyclic astronomy (some of it probably goes back to Hipparchus).